# Binomial related question on Column Property

Tags: combinatorics

If $m,n \in {N^ + },n \ge m$, prove that $\left( {m + 1} \right){}^m{C_m} + \left( {m + 2} \right){}^{m + 1}{C_m} + \left( {m + 3} \right){}^{m + 2}{C_m} + .... + n{}^{n - 1}{C_m} + \left( {n + 1} \right){}^n{C_m} = \left( {m + 1} \right){}^{n + 2}{C_{m + 2}}$.

My approach is as follow $\left( m \right){}^m{C_m} + \left( {m + 1} \right){}^{m + 1}{C_m} + \left( {m + 2} \right){}^{m + 2}{C_m} + .... + \left( {n - 1} \right){}^{n - 1}{C_m} + n.{}^n{C_m} = T$

${}^m{C_m} + {}^{m + 1}{C_m} + {}^{m + 2}{C_m} + .... + {}^{n - 1}{C_m} + {}^n{C_m} = U$

Where $U = {}^m{C_m} + {}^{m + 1}{C_m} + {}^{m + 2}{C_m} + .... + {}^n{C_m} = {}^{n + 1}{C_{m + 1}}$ by column properety

How do we calculate the value of T and then combine T+U to get the desired result.

Comment: You are summing up terms like $(n+1)\binom{n}k$. Use the identity $(n+1)\binom{n}k=(k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}$.

Comment: Yes i understood the concept